# How do I fetch the count from MS Access tables using group by clause?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having an absolute brain breakdown with this SQL query, I'm hoping someone can shine some light with what I should be doing.

I have the following tables and they are linked by "anumber";

```
athletes
--------
anumber     (id)
acountry    ('Australia','Japan')
aname

result_placing
--------------
result_id       id
anumber         (id linked to athletes)
result_placing  (Gold, Silver or null)
```

I would like to get a list of countries with how many gold, silver results associated. so output like:

```
country     | resul_placing | result_count
----------- | ------------- | ------------
Australia   | Gold          |       2
Australia   | Silver        |       1
```

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT      acountry 
FROM        athletes 
INNER JOIN  result_placing 
ON          athletes.anumber = result_placing.anumber
```

Which shows

```
 Australia | Gold   |
 Australia | Silver |
```

Just not sure how to get the count of each. I tried count(distinct) but Access doesn't like it.

As soon as I use Count in it like:

```
SELECT      a.acountry
        ,   r.placing
        ,   count(a.acountry) 
FROM        athlete         a 
INNER JOIN  result_place    r 
ON          a.anumber       = r.anumber
```

I receive:

*`You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'acountry' as part of an aggregate function`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT      a.acountry
        ,   r.result_placing
        ,   sum(*) as cnt 
FROM        athletes        a 
RIGHT JOIN  result_placing  r 
ON          a.anumber       = r.anumber 
GROUP BY    a.acountry
        ,   r.result_placing 
ORDER BY    a.acountry
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this out, but here goes. You need to use group by. Please try the following query

```
SELECT a.acountry, r.result_placing, count(a.acountry) FROM athletes a INNER JOIN     result_placing r ON a.anumber = r.anumber group by a.acountry, r.result_placing
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Just updated question with what happens if I try to use a count.

Comment: you need to have a group by as well. Please add group by a.acountry, r.result_placing to the end of your query

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to query the data using *LEFT OUTER JOIN* and *GROUP BY*.

*`Script`*:

```
SELECT              a.acountry
                ,   IIf(r.result_placing = '' 
                        OR IsNull(r.result_placing), 
                        'n/a', 
                        r.result_placing
                    ) AS medal
                ,   COUNT(r.result_id) AS medalcount
FROM                athletes a
LEFT OUTER JOIN     result_placing r
ON                  a.anumber = r.anumber
GROUP BY            a.acountry
                ,   r.result_placing
```

*`Table Data`*:

*athletes* table data

[image: athletes]

*results_placing* table data

[image: results_placings]

*`Output`*:

Query output

[image: query]